# Android application uninstalling earlier version

Tags: android

I have developed different versions of an android applications and exported them to my phone.I have renamed the different apk files like Myapp1.0.apk,MyApp1.1.apk etc.I have also given different names to all the apps.But whenever I am installing a specific version of the app,the previous version is getting automatically uninstalled.
I am confused what is uninstalling the earlier app version automatically??

Can anybody throw some light on this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android works by package name.  If you install another app with the same package name, it replaces the previous app with that package name.  Its how Android does updates.  The name of the apk means nothing.

Also, if you try to install another apk with the same package name signed by a different key, it will fail due to security checks-  so if you work with multiple people on the same app, you should share debug keys to prevent having to manually uninstall all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your package is probably the same in every version. This is what identifies your application in the android system. So the versions you install are just new version of the same app... and if you install a new version android automatically removes the old version.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

the identity of an android application is it's application package. If you use a same package name then it will replace the existing apps. That's how the update of app works.

If you want to run two instance of same app in a device for some purposes, then just rename the application package and install.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the Same package Name for all the versions and in android you can't install two applications with same package try to change the package name and try to install it again hope this will work....